# CSS - Dropdown menu child item drags the whole style one level down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have on main Menu that works totally fine without child menu items.
But now i have to add additional items and wanted to do a drop down Menu.

The Menu item "Services" is parent of "test" there should be a clean line, but when opening "Services" the border of the whole menu expands with "test" there should only be a small border the same length as "Services" surrounding "test".
For this to work i have to edit "current active deeper parent" or "nav-child unstyled small" if i'm correctly.
If possible you should even only need to hover over "Services" to trigger the dropdown menu.

```css
.flowmenu {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
  padding-left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.flowmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding: 0;
}
.flowmenu ul li {
  position: relative;
}
.flowmenu li > a {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #555555;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Corbel', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.flowmenu li.active {
  background: #222222;
}
```

```html
<div class="navfix">
  <ul class="nav menu flowmenu li">
    <li class="item-435"><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-485"><a href="/">Communication</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-486 current active deeper parent"><a href="/services">Services</a>
      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-579"><a href="/services/test">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-487"><a href="/">Languages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-488"><a href="/">Network</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent list item of the `<ul>` has to be position relative if you want a dropdown menu

the `<ul>` it self can be  position absolute so it appears nicely under the parent. I made a [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aLdg50qt/)

**Most important changes:**

```
.flowmenu > li {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding: 0;
}

.flowmenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display:block; /* or none */
  width:100%;
  background: #222222;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Hope this helps! I didn't completly styled the dropdown maybe it's better to do that yourself

```css
.flowmenu {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
  padding-left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.flowmenu > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding: 0;
}
.flowmenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flowmenu ul > li {
  display: block;
}
.flowmenu li > a {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #555555;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Corbel', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.flowmenu > li.active {
  background: #222222;
}
.flowmenu > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navfix">
  <ul class="nav menu flowmenu li">
    <li class="item-435"><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-485"><a href="/">Communication</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-486 current active deeper parent"><a href="/services">Services</a>
      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-579"><a href="/services/test">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-487"><a href="/">Languages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-488"><a href="/">Network</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved it completely! Wouldn't have thought it'll take so few changes.

Comment: Sorry for asking this here but is there a way to push the child element i px to the left to align it with my style?